# Android sqlite NOT IN

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have db with scheme
1. _id 
2. word

And i have ArrayList with for example 5 words (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)

What is the best way to construct query to get words from DB which don't contain words from ArrayList?

Sowthing like

> Select * from MYTABLE where WORD not in "all words from
>   ArrayList"

Answer (score 3):

Build a string representing the set of words, and use that as an argument to the query.

```
StringBuilder wordSet = new StringBuilder();
wordSet.append('(');
for( String word : wordsList )
{
    if(wordSet.length() > 1)
        wordSet.append(',');
    wordSet.append(word);
}
wordSet.append(')');
```

Comment: may be it is possible to make using dbHelper.query() method and pass List as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Query

Select * from mytable

Use the except operator against a selection containing words in array list
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#EXCEPT_operator

Comment: This is possible, but it's very cumbersome to get the words from the arraylist into a query, and it would not be any more efficient.